# "Connection to tcp://smtp.sendgrid.net:587 Timed Out" (SOMETIMES) but mail settings configured correctly

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, sendgrid

Background:
We are using Laravel v8.83.5 running on PHP 7.3 Amazon Linux EC2 instance which is powered by an Elastic Load Balancer. The email provider is Sendgrid and emails are sent in `redis` queue which runs on an ElastiCache instance within the same VPC. The sendgrid settings are configured correctly as the emails do send in the same server setup. To run the queues, we use a supervisor running in the background. Outgoing Port 587 is enabled on the instances and does work as emails do get sent.

Problem
Lately, we have noticed that whenever the server auto scale, we start getting the error `Connection to tcp://smtp.sendgrid.net:587 Timed Out` whenever an email is sent. The email may or may not include attachments. A publicly shared stack trace is available at https://flareapp.io/share/pPvOWq67#F48. This does not happen for all emails in the app but for a certain set of emails that are dispatched by the system as per the business logic in the background.
To temporarily try to fix the issue, we upgraded our autoscaling rule to scale down to just 1 instance when it was autoscaled to 2 and that didn't throw the error when the same email event was tried.

We tried contacting sendgrid to enquire about any throttle limits but they responded that no recent throttling was noticed on their end.

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve timeout errors in my case (though on a different hosting environment) by following the [official recommendation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/troubleshooting-delays-and-latency) and utilizing the [`SendGrid API`](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started) instead `SMTP`. There are mail drivers for Laravel available, e.g. the [Laravel SendGrid Driver](https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver), for doing so.